# How can i create a List type of MailKit message?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mailkit

Today now I'm using Mime like this:

```
List<OpenPop.Mime.Message> allMessages;
```

But then later in my code I'm doing:

```
private int numberofallmessages = 0;
     private int countMsg = 0;

     private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
     {
         List<string> uids = new List<string>();
         using (var client = new Pop3Client())
         {
             client.Connect(textServer.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textPort.Text), ssl);
             client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

             client.Authenticate(textUser.Text, textPassword.Text);
             int messageCount = client.Count() - 1;
             allMessages = new List<OpenPop.Mime.Message>(messageCount);

             for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
             {
                 if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
                 {
                     e.Cancel = true;
                     return;
                 }
                 string currentUidOnServer = uids[i];
                 if (!seenUids.Contains(currentUidOnServer))
                 {
                     if (i > 0)
                     allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
```

But of course I'm getting error on the line:

```
allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
```

The error is:

> Error 7   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(OpenPop.Mime.Message)' has some invalid arguments

and

> Error 8   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MimeKit.MimeMessage' to 'OpenPop.Mime.Message'

I can't find the MailKit message only of the OpenPop so i can't create a List of all the MailKit messages type.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MimeKit.MimeMessage>
```